# Google Drive SDK sample python DrEdit not working (flashed upon authentication, editor not shown)

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have been trying to setup the sample DrEdit in python following all the instructions on the readme at the github distribution of the python code.

the app is set up at:
https://speedy-filament-420.appspot.com

when i authenticate, it flashes then nothing shows.

A working one should show an editor, akin to the following:
http://idning-gdrive-test.appspot.com/

Is there any other thing I need to do other than the setup instructions to get the sample to work?

Could someone shed some light on where the issue could be please? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading your link and watching the Javascript console, I see an error on line 15 of app.js

```
  13:  angular.module('app', ['app.filters', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])
  14:      .constant('saveInterval', 15000)
  15:      .constant('appId', [[YOUR APPLICATION ID]]) // Please replace this with your Application ID.
        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/edit/:id', {
                templateUrl: '/public/partials/editor.html',
                controller: EditorCtrl})
            .otherwise({redirectTo:'/edit/'});
    }]);
```

Comment: now the editor shows, am exploring if there' other issue. Thank you so much. May I know where I can access this console to inspect future problems myself? Thank you again.

Comment: found it in chrome:) thank you.

Comment: NP.  On Stackoverflow, it's polite to share your knowledge for those who may follow. On Chrome, hit ctrl-shift-j